# DLL files are shown ignored in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net

I searched this in stack some peoples post the answers that's pretty good

For this because the file is being ignored

*You just need to right click the ignore file -> Git -> Add ignored file to source control.*

I DID THE THIS WAY
but some ddl files there is no option.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have 2 issues:

Do you want the file(s) in question NOT to be part of your repo on git-hub, or are you wanting the file(s) in question to NOT be part of the asp.net application build?

On top of this issue is of course is the type of web site you have for the git-hub repo.

So, of course the "bin" folder should not be part of the repo, but there ARE exceptions. If you using a web site "application", then you do NOT want nor need the bin file to be included in the repo.

In other words, when you build the site, then the bin folder is (and should be) created from scratch.

So, if you have some .dll you don't want included? Then don't include it in your project.

I mean, either you need/want and will use that .dll, or you will not, right?

So, from visual studio (not git), then you right click, and choose to include the .dll in the compile out (bin folder) like this:

[image]

So, really, I want the above .dll included in the bin folder. If I don't want this .dll to be included in the repo, then REMOVE it from the project.

So, you control if a .dll is included or not by right click on the .dll, and choose the build options (such as copy always). So, the issue of "including" the .dll in the project (and the "copy always" on build) are somthing you control outside of git-hub.

It makes VERY little sense to include and have .dll's in your project, but THEN decide to NOT include in the git-hub repo. Why would you want to do that, since then if I pull your repo, I'll be missing .dll's then, right?

So, if you don't want that .dll included in your project? Then REMOVE it from your project.

On the other hand, if that .dll's is imporant, required, and you NEED that .dll? Then you HAVE to include that .dll, since you need it, right?

So, it not clear why you want the .dll in the project, but NOT included in the repo?

but, in your screen shot?

The "option" to exclude is MOST certainly visible in your screen shot. The option you are looking for is "ignore and un-track" item.

So, the option being suggested to you is visible, and the option to "ignore" is in fact called "ignore and un-track" item.

So, keep in mind the VAST difference of controlling .dll's in your build process in vs as compared to that of including (or not) in your repo. They are 2 difference concepts.